# Change Page with useState, depending on websocket message 'Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I use the 'stompjs' and 'sockjs-client' for my websocket connection. When I receive the message, I want to change the page from 'LoginPage' to 'GamePage'. I already tried to implement useEffects, but had no success. I think it's because of 'stompClient.subsribe' that I couldn't implement a useEffect, but maybe I just did something wrong.

```
const onConnected = () => {
        stompClient.subscribe('/client/playerList', function (greeting) {
            setPlayers(JSON.parse(greeting.body));
            if (JSON.parse(greeting.body).length <= 4 && !isPartyFull) {
                setUserJoint(true);
            }
        });
```

```
if (userJoint) {
        return (
            <PlayerContext.Provider
                value={{
                    players,
                    stompClient
                }}
            >
                <GamePage />
            </PlayerContext.Provider>
        );
    }
    return (
        <PlayerContext.Provider value={{ stompClient }}>
            <LoginPage />;
        </PlayerContext.Provider>
    );
```

I have solved it as follows, but I don't like this solution.
Hope someone has a better idea how i could solve it.

```
return (
        <PlayerContext.Provider value={{ players, stompClient }}>
            <LoginPage userJoint={userJoint} />
            <GamePage userJoint={userJoint} />
        </PlayerContext.Provider>
    );
```

Depending on the state, one of the two is always an empty div. In both pages.

```
return userJoint === true ? (
        <div></div>
    ) : (
        <div className="flex h-full">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that the only usage of `userJoint` in `LoginPage` and `GamePage` is to decide whether to display, so I am leaving it out of those components' props below. It's fairly standard in react to do something like the following:

```js
return (
  <PlayerContext.Provider value={{ players, stompClient }}>
    {userJoint ? <LoginPage /> : <GamePage />}
  </PlayerContext.Provider>
);
```

The solves the problem of having `LoginPage` and `GamePage` deciding whether to display themselves or an empty `div` based on their props, which seems like a bit of an anti-pattern to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Have tried it and unfortunately still get the same error.

Comment: Can you share a bit more of your code for context? It's very helpful when OP provides a minimal reproducible example in a snippet so that responders can see the error for themselves. In your case, it doesn't really seem like the websocket is important to your question, so maybe factor that part out and give an example with just the breaking code and a simple mock for the websocket, e.g. a toggle button. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/12162258 for how to write react snippets (working examples at the bottom)